# Enum.GetName display Annotation

Tags: c#, enums, annotations

I have a enum that I am able to display in a `EnumDropDownListFor` with no problem and save the enum. Now I am trying to take that value from my record and display the DataAnnotation for it. I have been trying `Enum.GetName` however coming across some issues.

my enum -

```
public enum LandOwner
    {
        [Display(Name = "Yes")]
        Y =1 ,
        [Display(Name = "No")]
        N =2,
        [Display(Name = "No Nearby Land Owner")]
        O =3
    }

    public LandOwner ownerDropDown { get; set; }
```

When I save the record it save an Y, N or O.

My `Enum.GetName` - where `Model.LandOwnersNotified` is the Y, N, or O.

```
@Enum.GetName(typeof(OpenBurn.Models.BurnPile.LandOwner), Model.LandownersNotified)
```

However when I run this I get the following error -

*The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.\r\nParameter name: value*

When I change the Enum.GetName to

```
 @Enum.GetName(typeof(OpenBurn.Models.BurnPile.LandOwner), 1)
```

I know the latter part of the `Enum.GetName` is looking for an int however doesn't the `Model.LandownersNotified` in combination with the enum provide that?

I will receive the Y for everything. At no time do I receive the `[Display(name="...")]`.

Comment: Does @Html.DisplayFor() not work for you?

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor() does not give me the option for my enum.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say i understand what you are trying to do.  But  `@Enum.GetName` is designed to return the name for the value of the enum.   So you can't pass the enum to it.

```
Model.LandownersNotified.ToString() -> Y,N,O
(int)Model.LandownersNotified -> 1,2,3
```

Comment: Would you use a '@Html.DisplayFor' with that?

Comment: When the database has recorded a 'Y' for LandOwnersNotified I would like to Display a 'Yes' on the Delete, Edit, Details and Index views.